# What is screwing up my pickling of scikit learn model objects?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, pickle

Im at least assuming something is screwing that up...
here is what is going on.  I am making ML models for currency pairs in the foreign exchange market.  I make one model for each pair im looking at.  So, I have 8 models.

I do the following:

1.) make a model based on data, from a csv file, for each pair.  kind of like this:

```
namelist = ['usdcad', 'eurjpy', 'usdjpy', 'gbpjpy', 'audusd', 'usdchf', 'nzdusd', 'gbpusd', 'eurusd']


for filename in namelist:

with open(filename+"/all.csv",'r') as dest_f:
    data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f,
                           delimiter = ",",
                           quotechar = '"')
    data = [data for data in data_iter]

    ##do some stuff to organize the data

    model50 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    model50.fit(X, Y50)

    afile = open(r''+filename+'.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(model50, afile)
    afile.close()
```

Then in another file I load realtime data, which I use as input for my model, I save that data to csvs

```
namelist = ['USDCAD', 'EURJPY', 'USDJPY', 'GBPJPY', 'AUDUSD', 'USDCHF', 'USDCAD', 'NZDUSD', 'GBPUSD', 'EURUSD']

for name in namelist:
CSV_URL = 'REMOVED BECAUSE IT HAS MY KEY'+name

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    del my_list[:18]
    del my_list[-1]
    with open(name+".csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(my_list)
```

Then finally, I run all my predictions at once:

```
namelist = ['USDCAD', 'EURJPY', 'USDJPY', 'GBPJPY', 'AUDUSD', 'USDCHF', 'USDCAD', 'NZDUSD', 'GBPUSD', 'EURUSD']


for name in namelist:

with open(name+".csv",'r') as dest_f:
    data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f,
                           delimiter = ",",
                           quotechar = '"')
    res = [data for data in data_iter]


res = [[x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6]] for x in res]
input = np.zeros((1,len(res)*4))
indx = 0
while 1:
    for row in res:
        for col in row:
            input[0,indx] = float(col)
            indx += 1
    break   

pname = name.lower()    

file = open(r''+pname+'.pkl', 'rb')
mymodel = pickle.load(file)
file.close()    

prediction = mymodel.predict(input)
```

sorry about any small formatting errors, I am still pretty bad at using this site properly.

anyways, so what actually happens here is that two of my predictions are correct, clearly the model is working right.  the other 6 predictions make NO SENSE AT ALL.  It's like it's trying to use one of the other models, but it shouldn't be....  Or like the wrong model gets pickled to a filename.  I've examined the inputs, the files, they are all correct.  Furthermore, using the exact same CSV files, I used the exact same techniques to make a model and predict JUST usdcad, and it works great!  But the usdcad prediction comes out totally wrong when I use the scripts below.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?  I can't figure it out.  Thanks.

**QUICK EDIT:
I've confirmed that the problem is that it is with the pickled models.  It's overwriting them or keeping old model objects in memory or something...

EDIT2:  Some extra info
I have discovered that if I pickle my model, and then load it, and then use it - all in the same script, then it works fine.  If I pickle my model, and then load it in another script (using the exact same code), it does not work correctly.  This is the case even when I only make one model.

Comment: You should try running `pickle.load` with a specified encoding to see if that fixes your issue on import.